# the order of appearance when using two geom_ functions

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to plot predicted lines and those confidence intervals using ggplot2 and its geom_point and geom_ribbon.

While, I usually use geom_smooth, in this case, the "dataset" is fitted values on each of the specific values.

[image: Please see this graph]

Hence, geom_line represents the predicted line, and geom_ribbon shows those confidence intervals.

The thing is overlapping:
**In geom_line, the value 1 of the group is on the top; however, in geom_ribbon, the value 0 of the group is on the top. So it is a bit confusing.**

```
ggplot(data = fitt_busi_prior_re_vig,
       aes(y = predicted, x = x, color = group, group = group, shape =group, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)) + 
  facet_grid(~facet) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = seq(0, 1), breaks  = seq(0, 1, 0.1)) +  
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun = mean, linewidth = 1.3) +
  geom_ribbon(alpha = 0.3)+
  xlab("") + ylab("") + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. I'm not sure I see what you are seeing. it looks like the greenish group is always on top.

Comment: Try facet on 2 variables: `ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(vars(drv), vars(cyl))` see: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html

Comment: @MrFlick Sorry, I'll upload reproducible codes. 
If you look closely, you can see the greener line is on top of the red one, but at the bottom of the red "ribbon". This is the all I want to fix!

Comment: You are drawing the ribbons on top of the lines. Maybe just do `+geom_ribbon` before `+stat_summary` so it's underneath? The order in which you add the geoms matters.

Comment: This is a tricky question which I've seen here before but can't find -- how do you make series which appear in multiple layers plot sequentially, i.e. with all the layers of series A underneath all the layers of series B. That's not how ggplot2 typically works, so the cleanest solution I've seen has been to make a new custom geom that combines the two. Can someone find that?

Comment: Here's how to make a custom geom that combines two or more geoms. This allows you to more easily make the plot order consistent across layers: https://ggplot2-book.org/extensions#sec-combining-multiple-geoms